# List of currently open ENS bids

Tags: ens

Is there any website which lists all of the currently open ENS bids?

https://etherscan.io/ens does list them, but amidst a lot of other noise.

Ideally, I'd like to see the time remaining before the 72 hrs auction and 48 hrs reveal expires.

Comment: I haven't seen anything much better than that etherscan list, maybe because it would go against the ethos of ENS. All a list like that would do is make it easier for snipers/squatters to jump on names that other people find valuable.